# Java HashMaps why does this return null?

Tags: java, hashmap

I setup a test jar app to run for my other program I have been working on this for hours and i cant find a reason for why it returns null. Thanks for helping!

hashy.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class hashy {

private static HashMap<String, Integer> targets = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashymashy mash = new Hashymashy();
    mash.hashyMash();
    String name = "Bobby";
    int num = 10;

    targets.put(name, num);

    if (targets.containsKey(name) == true) {
        System.out.println("It contains a key!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It does not contain a key!");
    }
    if (targets.containsValue(num) == true) {
        System.out.println("It contains a value");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It does not contain a value!");
    }
}
public HashMap<String,Integer> getTargets(){
    return targets;
}
}
```

Hashymashy.java

```
 public class Hashymashy {

public void hashyMash(){
    hashy h = new hashy();
    String name = "Bobby";
    Integer fnum = h.getTargets().get(name);

    System.out.println("Number is "+fnum+"!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to retrieve the value associated with *"Bobby"* before adding it to the `HashMap`.

```
mash.hashyMash();
```

is called before `targets.put(name, num);`, so

```
Integer fnum = h.getTargets().get("Bobby");
```

will return `null` since there is no `"Bobby"` **yet**.

**PS**: seems like a bad design to me, since `Hashymashy` classes create instances of `hashy` classes & vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks i need to configure something on my program then